# Terminating Processes: difference between contex cancellation and kill signal

Tags: go

```golang
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "1000")

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        //cmd.Process.Signal(os.Kill)
        //cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)
        cancel()

    }()

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("Finishing...")
}
```

Are there any differences between `cancel` and `Signal(os.Kill)`? They cause the same error.

How can I distinguish between a kill signal and termination due to an error? Only by checking `err.Error() == "signal: killed"`?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [exec.CommandContext](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext) give you the answer to this one:

> The provided context is used to kill the process (by calling os.Process.Kill) if the context becomes done before the command completes on its own.

In turn, [os.Process.Kill](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Kill) calls the os-specific `kill()` function, which is the following for [posix](https://golang.org/src/os/exec_posix.go#L65):

```golang
func (p *Process) kill() error {
    return p.Signal(Kill)
}
```

So both end up calling `Signal(os.Kill)`.

As for how to tell the difference, you have two basic options:

- parse the error which can be fragile (although a straight up check against `signal: killed` is not too bad
- check the exit code, it **should** be 137 when terminated by `SIGKILL`